# Android startActivity error when passing (through intent) jpg image file in byteArray, not when passing png image file

Tags: android, image, android-intent, start-activity

I'm trying to send jpg and png image file from one activity(ImageUploadActivity) to another activity(ImageResultActivity). The image is selected from gallery or taken from camera.

```
//Select image from gallery
//belongs to ImageUploadActivity

Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
File file = new File("testPic.png");
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("testPic.png" , 0);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50 , fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Below here are the code lines that I try to send image with intent.
It works well when I pass PNG format, but about JPG format it returns RuntimeError because of the startActivity(). I put this code in Handler because I needed to show existed screen for a little time before start the new activity.

```
//belongs to ImageUploadActivity's one button's clicklistener

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bStream);
        byte[] byteArray = bStream.toByteArray();
        Intent i = new Intent(ImageUploadActivity.this,ImageResultActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        i.putExtra("imageArrInput", byteArray);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}, 1500);
```

And this is full error trace

```
07-13 10:10:00.075 3731-3749/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 76)
07-13 10:10:02.254 15346-15346/example.com.samsung.humintec E/aaaa: [B@20377d1
        i.putExtra("imageArrInput", byteArray);
    Stream.flush();
    bStream.close();
07-13 10:10:02.261 15346-15346/example.com.samsung.humintec E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 4512136)
07-13 10:10:02.267 15346-15346/example.com.samsung.humintec E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: example.com.samsung.humintec, PID: 15346
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1533)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4399)
            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:65)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4358)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:711)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4682)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4650)
            at example.com.samsung.humintec.Activity.ImageUploadActivity$2.run(ImageUploadActivity.java:119)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
         Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 4512136 bytes
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:628)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3529)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1526)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4399) 
            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54) 
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:65) 
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4358) 
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:711) 
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4682) 
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4650) 
            at example.com.samsung.humintec.Activity.ImageUploadActivity$2.run(ImageUploadActivity.java:119) 
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: It would help if you would also post the full error trace (stack trace) and a bit more context about where these pieces of code are located in your activity. Why is the second code in a postDelayed call?

Comment: @TylerV  I edited the question, as you said. What I wanted to show for a little is progressBar.

Answer (score 1):

You got a `TransactionTooLargeException`

> The key to avoiding TransactionTooLargeException is to keep all
>   transactions relatively small. Try to minimize the amount of memory
>   needed to create a Parcel for the arguments and the return value of
>   the remote procedure call. Avoid transferring huge arrays of strings
>   or large bitmaps. If possible, try to break up big requests into
>   smaller pieces.

Or you can see more in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException)

And I don't know why you need passing it via intent, because you can get it in second activity.

So my solution is that just send a key (maybe name of this image) and get it in second activity (using that key) as below

Send a key

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    i.putExtra("image_name", yourImageName);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }, 1500);
```

And in second activity:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_name");
try {
    FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    is.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much, now I notice that I overlooked some important thing that intent is inproper for a large object.

Answer (score 0):

Intent is not suitable for passing large object since Intent will serialize and deserialize the object and that's not easy for a large object.

If your project uses EventBus, you can pass your image object by EventBus because EventBus only passes the reference of an object.

If you don't want to use EventBus or you want to do inter-process passing (which EventBus can't), than @GianhTran's way, i.e. save the image as a file in a non-ui thread and read the image in your newly started activity will be a choice.

Comment: Thank you so much too, you gave a good advice to me I will keep this in mind. Hope I will use EventBus somewhere properly.